# Как конвертировать строку представляющую дату-время в число?

Tags: c++, c

Есть строка которая представляет собой дату-время в текущей локали. Как из этой даты я могу получить ее числовое значение.

Например в Windows есть тип `_variant_t`, c помощью которого можно решить эту задачу так:

```
std::wstring wstr("01/01/2015");
_variant_t src(str.c_str());
_variant_t dest;
::VariantChangeType( &dest, &src, 0, VT_DATE )
```

И в этом случае не нужно указывать какой формат строки я подаю. Как это можно сделать кросс-платформенным способом? В идеале с помощью стандартной библиотеки. Необязательно в `VT_DATE`, подходит любой числовой тип.

Можно еще получить формат даты-времени у системы, но как это сделать? Есть функция `localeconv()` она позволяет получить специфичные для локали вещи: десятичный разделитель, денежный знак и так далее, но вот формата времени там нет.

Comment: Вот есть [`::std::get_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time), с форматом `%c` или `%x` должно парсить.

Comment: `get_time` распарсит только время. Например если подать строку "14:45:53" то все хорошо, а если "01.01.2013" то нет

Comment: Мне кажется. что два Ваших утверждения: *представляет собой дату-время в текущей локали* и *не нужно указывать какой формат строки* взаимно исключают друг друга. Либо фиксированный формат, либо произвольгый... Вы чего желаете добиться?

Comment: Как раз-таки не противоречит. Рассмотрим пример: мне нужно расспарсить строку содержащую время.  Вопрос: откуда возьмется строка? Возможно она будет получена из `std::tm` какой-нибудь функцией(например `std::put_time` c форматом `%c` или другой аналогичной),  с разделителем и порядком месяц-день-год принятыми в текущей локали. Но ведь я уже установил что функция понимает только "dd.mm.yyyy" а получаю "mm.dd.yy" потому-что такой формат установлен в локали. Поэтому я хочу отвязаться от жесткого формата и перейти на формат установленный в локали.

Comment: В идеале я хочу поведение `VariantChangeType`но кросс-платформенное.